# Optimize retrieval of records when quering between multiple collections in marklogic

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I am trying to query between 2 collections having a join condition between them,
Say the 2 documents are:

Collection 1: Company (1M documents)

Company Documents:

```
<Company>
 <CompanyName>XYZ</CompanyName>  
 <Description>ABC</Description>
  .
  .
</Company>
```

Collection 2: Employee (1M documents)

XML:

```
<Employee>
 <EmpName>john</EmpName>  
 <CompanyName>XYZ</CompanyName>  
  .
  .
</Employee>
```

The Query I am using is,

```
for $company in collection('Company'), $employee in collection('Employee')
where ( $company/Company/CompanyName eq $employee/Employee/CompanyName)
return document-uri($company)
```

when there are less documents in both collections, able to fetch the records,
but when i do stress testing say, 1M records in both collections, in this case takes a lot of time and results in time limit exceeded exception. Is there a way to optimize this query?

I have tried the following methods,
assuming there exists a range index for CompanyName,

```
for $company in collection('Company'), $employee in cts:values(cts:path-reference('/Employee/CompanyName'))
where ( $company/Company/CompanyName eq $employee)
return document-uri($company)
```

if companyName is unique then the above Query will not optimize much. I need a way which can work for both distinct and duplicate value of elements

Answer (score 3):

Leveraging indexes and cts:* functions can speed this up dramatically.

Use [`cts:element-values()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-values) to retrieve the set of `CompanyName` values from the documents in the `Employee` collection.

Use [`cts:uris()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris) to retrieve the set of document URIs from the `Company` collection that have `CompanyName` values from the set of values from the Employee documents using [`cts:element-range-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-range-query).

```
let $CompanyName := xs:QName("CompanyName")
let $employee-companies := cts:element-values($CompanyName, "", (), cts:collection-query("Employee"))
return
  cts:uris("", (), cts:and-query((
    cts:collection-query("Company"), 
    cts:element-range-query($CompanyName, "=", $employee-companies) 
  )))
```